# Custom struct in AngelScript

Tags: c, angelscript

Maybe somebody know. How can I send my custom c-struct, from my c-application to AngelScript-script?  At the moment, I just use the standard types (char*, uint8_t)

Best regards.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Quick googling revealed [a lot of info](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/sdk/docs/manual/doc_reg_objprop.html) regarding registering objects and object properties. Please read the manual and try find solution, and then ask if you have specific problem. Question as it's now is too broad and shows no research effort.

Comment: @user694733 Oh! I missed this paragraph. Ty!